# Models and their meaning in a proof of any formula

Tags: logic, proof-writing, first-order-logic

Behind the scenes all formula $\phi$, we must define a model, M = (F, P) over a Universe, where F = set of Functions and P = set of Predicates,  on a table of free variables in $\phi$ ?
Ie any $\phi$ that i desire to prove i should create a model over a particular universe?

---

Suppose we want to prove a assertion on the theory of sets. And we have the axioms, theorems, definitions, and all these things. Whenever i want to prove assertions, we should create or use a pre-existing model or they aren't related at all, how it works?

For example, assuming this statement over sets:
|A-B| = |A| - |A $\cup$ B| .

And what about an assertion about a behavior of peoples or something else.

Comment: Can you clarify your question? It is hard to understand.

Comment: One doesn’t create a model to prove a theorem. Instead, one creates a model to show that a formula is consistent with the axioms, i.e., its negation cannot be proven from the axioms.

Comment: If you want to prove an assertion about sets, then you find a direct proof, not create a model. However, if you want to show that a formula is consistent with the axioms, then you create a model of the axioms that satisfies the formula. For example, Gödel showed that the Axiom of Choice ($ \mathsf{AC} $) and the Continuum Hypothesis ($ \mathsf{CH} $) are consistent with the Zermelo-Fraenkel Axioms ($ \mathsf{ZF} $) by creating a special model of $ \mathsf{ZF} $ called the ‘constructible universe’. It is therefore impossible to disprove $ \mathsf{AC} $ or $ \mathsf{CH} $ within $ \mathsf{ZF} $.

Comment: @Argument thanks, pretty enlightening. My doubt i guess is around that, i have to find a direct proof And when i'm finding a direct proof, or whatever other kind of proof how that process is related to the models i have to create in first order logic, for example?

Answer (score 0):

No, for proving a formula $\varphi$ it's not suffice to create a model. Because according to soundness theorem if a formula is provable it is valid in all models, and according to completeness theorem for proving a formula it suffices to prove it is valid in all models( Is it possible $?!$ ).
I hope I could answer to your question.